# How to integrate an integral which contain an oscillatory term $e^{\imath x\cdot p}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, oscillatory-integral

I need to evaluate a integral $$f(p)=\int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}e^{-\imath x\cdot p}, $$I tried a lot, but unable to find a method to integrate due to the presence of oscillatory term $e^{\imath x\cdot p}$.

Please give some ideas to evaluate this integral.

Comment: Please share in more detail what you have tried.

Comment: If the integral is not oscillatory, we can do it,  that's what I tried, but it's not the thing I wanted, can you please help @Ramanujan

Comment: Laplace transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition

Comment: $\int_0^\infty x^2/\sqrt {x^2 + a^2} \, e^{-i p x} dx$ and $\int_0^\infty x/\sqrt {x^2 + a^2} \, e^{-i p x} dx$ diverge for real $p$, but they make sense if interpreted as Fourier transforms:
$$\mathcal F {\left[ x \mapsto \frac {x^2 H(x)} {2 \sqrt {x^2 + a^2}} \right]}(p) =
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac {x^2} {2 \sqrt {x^2 + a^2}} - \frac x 2 \right)
 e^{-i p x} dx +
\mathcal F {\left[ x \mapsto \frac {x H(x)} 2 \right]}(p).$$
The regular part has a closed form in terms of Bessel and Struve functions.

Answer (score 1):

This improper integral does not converge as asymptotically the absolute value of the integrand namely $|f(x)| \sim x, x\in(0,\infty).$ Hence, $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ diverges.

Comment: I think the integral can be done in asymptotic limit as $p\to \infty$, please check this link  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105045/three-integrals-in-peskins-textbook

Comment: @QFT addict  in numerator we have $x$ there but here it is $x^2$.

Comment: What about if this integral is from −∞ to ∞?still diverge?@Z Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Z Ahmed.  Here is the case $a=0$, where it can be done in closed form.

For $p=1$ the graph of $\text{Re }\int \frac{x}{2} e^{-ix}\;dx$ looks like
[image: 1]
and the limit does not exist at $+\infty$.
For $p=3$ the graph of $\text{Re }\int \frac{x}{2} e^{-i3x}\;dx$ looks like
[image: 3]
and the limit does not exist at $+\infty$.  You can guess what the graph looks like for other real values of $p$.
Now it does converge for $\text{Im}\;p < 0$.  Here is $p=-1+i\, 2.5$
[image: -1+I*2/5]

Comment: What about if this integral is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?still diverge?@GEdgar